# OOM will appear when deployed in k8s when I use Chronicle-Map

Tags: kubernetes, out-of-memory, chronicle-map

Deploying on a dedicated host is normal, but deploying on k8s will appear oomkilled, it requires a lot of memory, does anyone know how to solve this problem.
version:3.16.0

---

Comment: Sometimes, the oomkilled behavior can be driven by CPU request limits, depending on the application, I would suggest to review that as well

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.